# Does the series $\sum 1/(n+\sqrt n)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the series $$ \sum \frac 1 {n+\sqrt n}$$ converge?
I tried telescoping sum and ended up with $$\sum \left(\frac 1 {\sqrt{n}} -\frac 1 {1+\sqrt n} \right).$$

Comment: Hint: $n \leq n + \sqrt{n} \leq 2 n$.

Answer (score 5):

Since $n \geq \sqrt{n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$, it may be deduced that $2n \geq n + \sqrt{n}$. Consequently, it holds that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n + \sqrt{n}} \geq \frac{1}{2n}
\end{align*}
whence we conclude the proposed series diverges due to the comparison test.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 3):

It diverges because the summand divided by $1/n$ converges to $1$ as $n \to \infty$ and the sum of $1/n$ is $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Beside inequalities, the integral test is very revealing since
$$\int_1^p \frac {dn} {n+\sqrt n}=2 \log \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{p}}{2}\right) $$

*For your curiosity*, using the simplest form of Euler-MacLaurin summation
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p \frac 1 {n+\sqrt n}=C+\log(p)+\frac{2}{\sqrt{p}}-\frac{1}{2p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^{3/2}}\right)$$

For this level of expansion
$$C=\frac{438905}{1572864}-2 \log (2) \sim 1$$

This gives an excellent estimate of $S_p$, the relative error being smaller than $0.10$% for $p>18$ and smaller than $0.01$% for $p>328$.